# One button within loop (mass_assignt)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form, which has loop as you can see below.

My aim:

```
text   | checkbox |
text2  | checkbox |
text3  | checkbox |
text4  | checkbox |
______
button
------
```

If I clicked on button my table changes if i choose checkbox of course. So its One button in one form which has one loop.

PROBLEM:

Only last one is pasted successfully, (dont know why) e.g if i changed last item, this is ok, but when i changed first one, second one for example and last one, i get changes only in last one :(

DOESNT SEE MY LOOP i think :(

my show view

```
<%= form_for :task, :url => { :controller => :tasks, :action => :update } do |f| %>

  <% @tasks.each_with_index do |task, index| %>

    <%= f.fields_for task do |task_form| %>

      <%= task_form.text_field :task %>  | <%= task_form.check_box :is_active %>  <%= task_form.hidden_field :id %>

    <% end %>

  <% end %>

  <br/><br/>

  <%= f.submit 'Update' %>


<% end %>
```

my controller:

```
 def show

    @tasks=Task.find(:all)

  end

  def update

    tasks=Task.find(:all, :conditions => ["id=?", params[:task][:id]])


    tasks.each do |task|

    task.task=params[:task][:task]
    task.save

    end
 end
```

And thats error i get:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"vn0DUQhRa2zBguCFRf/fY/cYnzKYAkio0MwDUd4/mC8=",
 "task"=>{"task"=>{"task"=>"dlaj testa!",
 "is_active"=>"1",
 "id"=>"11"}},
 "commit"=>"Update"}

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is saying that `tasks.each do |task|` is the cause. `tasks` is nil, which you define above.

Instead of

```
tasks=Task.find(:all, :conditions => ["id=?", params[:task][:id]])
```

I would probably write it as:

```
tasks = Task.where(id: params[:task][:id])
```

That will return an array of all of the tasks, even if it's an empty array.

Then calling `.each` should not fail, since it's empty.